# Changing color of certain words in a SWT Label?

Tags: java, swt, label

In Swing, its possible to use HTML to style the words on a label. E.g if I wanted a certain word on a label to be bolded or be of a different color, I could do that with HTML.

Is there an equivalent feature for SWT? Say if I had the words "A quick brown fox jumped over a lazy dog" as the text of a label, and I wanted to change the color of "fox" to be brown, how would I do that?

Comment: What about using [`StyledText`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FStyledText.html)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really need a `Label`, you can use the code below. Otherwise I would suggest a [`StyledText`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FStyledText.html) (as mentioned in the comments):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText("Blue and not blue");

    Color blue = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE);

    final TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(display);
    layout.setText("Blue and not blue");
    final TextStyle style = new TextStyle(display.getSystemFont(), blue, null);

    label.addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            layout.setStyle(style, 0, 3);
            layout.draw(event.gc, event.x, event.y);
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();

}
```

With `StyledText` it would look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    StyledText text = new StyledText(shell, SWT.NONE);
    text.setEditable(false);
    text.setEnabled(false);
    text.setText("Blue and not blue");

    Color blue = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE);

    StyleRange range = new StyleRange(0, 4, blue, null);

    text.setStyleRange(range);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: How would I do this via styled text?

Comment: Thanks! Is there a limit to how many styleranges you can set per the StyledText, or can you add as many as needed?

Comment: @ClickUpvote If you want to add multiple `StyleRange`s, use either the `setStyleRanges(StyleRange[] ranges)` method, or add them iteratively via the method shown above. AFAIK, there is no limit to the number, but remember that newly added ones will overwrite older ones if they overlap in their range.

Comment: One more q. Is it possible to add a LineBackgroundListener to a styledtext, so each time a new line is added to the styledtext, that listener will be called with just that line, so it can interpret that line and set the style ranges for specific words on that line if needed?

Comment: @ClickUpvote This you will have to test yourself ;) No, seriously: I don't know this one :D